# How to get the exact object from json output

Tags: php, json

I have a json encoded output like

```
"[{"COLUMN_NAME":"htag"},{"COLUMN_NAME":"title"},{"COLUMN_NAME":"sounds"},{"COLUMN_NAME":"recx"}]"
```

I want to get the column name alone in array and echo it in same php file

**CODE:**
This is what I did

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='dbname' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='tbname'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
$out[] = $row;
$reds =  json_encode($out);
```

Comment: You should not be using mysql_* by the way.

Comment: why is that any depreciations

Comment: @user2992174 See here http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php#function.mysql-connect-refsynopsisdiv

Comment: tell me yaar its vague doc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to get the column name alone in array

Small change:

```
$sql=mysql_query("SELECT `COLUMN_NAME` 
FROM `INFORMATION_SCHEMA`.`COLUMNS` 
WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA`='dbname' 
    AND `TABLE_NAME`='tbname'");
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
    $out[] = $row['COLUMN_NAME'];

//Column names are now in the array $out.
$reds =  json_encode($out);
```